# How to inherit interface from superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract

I have an interface with a superclass, a subclass, and a driver class. The interface must be implemented in the subclass, however, I am confused on how to do it. Do I implement the interface in the superclass and then extends the subclass? 
The superclass is called store.

The subclass is called retail, it should receive the superclass's constructor, the number of items sold, unit price, and sale price should be array arguments. This class implements two methods that are defined at interface.

The interface should have two methods.  One is the profit and the other is salary The profit method is to calculate the store profit in a week, and salary method is to calculate the store manager’s salary in a week.

```
/*
The interface should have two methods.
One is the “Profit” and the other is “Salary”.
The profit method is to calculate the store profit in a week, and salary         method
is to calculate the store manager’s salary in a week.
*/
public interface Interface {

    public void profit();
    public void salary();

}
```

```
/*
The store class is a super class that receives store location, 
manager name, hours worked, and hour rate.  
This class should have the constructor that receives all of these.  
It also should have get and set methods for each of fields. 
This class also has “toString()” to 
display restaurant location and manager’s name.
*/
public class Store {
    private String location;
    private String manager;
    private int hours;
    private int rate;

    public Store(String l, String m, int hrs, int r) {
        location = l;
        manager = m;
        hours = hrs;
        rate = r;
    }

    public void setLocation(String l) {
        location = l;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setName(String m) {
        manager = m;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setHours(int hrs) {
        hours = hrs;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setRate(int r) {
        rate = r;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "Store Location: " + location + "\n";
        result += "Manager name:" + manager + "\n";
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class Retail extends Store {
    private int items;
    private double unit;
    private double sale;

    public Retail(String l, String m, int hrs, int r,int i, double u, double s){
        super(l,m, hrs, r);
        items = i;
        unit = u;
        sale = s;
    }
    public void profit() {
        double[][] money = {{1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99},
                            {5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 8.99},
                            {150, 48, 350,20}};
        for (int i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < money[i].length; j++) {
                sum += money[i][j];
            }
        }
        double profit = items * ( s - u);
    }

    public void salary() {
        double pay = hrs * r;
        //double salary = pay - ( pay * 0.05);
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        double baseSalary = super.getHours();
    }

    public String toString() {
        result += super.getName(); // inherited from superclass
        String result = "Total Benefit: " + profit + "\n";
        result += "Salary: " + salary + "\n";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than use "creative" code formatting, best to stick with one of the well-established standards, as doing this will make your code much easier to read and to understand.

Comment: I tried to format it *somewhat* better, but it still can be improved

Comment: Yeah this formatting is honestly one of the worst I have ever seen.  Please look up Java formatting and Java best practices online and get some basic formatting knowledge.  It will help you understand your _own_ code greatly.  There is a reason why brackets end where they do, because it makes it obvious what is in the block.

Comment: And the general answer to your question is that sometimes the superclass implements the interface, and sometimes it doesn't, depending on need. If the super-class and all its children should exhibit the interface's claimed behaviors, then it should implement it.

Comment: @exionoblivion What kind of inheritance hierarchy are you looking for? Store with the methods of Interface, which will be inherited by Retail? Or just Retail with the methods of Interface? Both are possible.

Comment: Also please don't put a random semicolon as a placeholder.  Just use a `//TODO:` comment if you really need an obvious placeholder.

Comment: And the `Retail.java` code won't compile, which doesn't help us to understand it or to help allow us to format it. In fact, the code for that class is a bit of a mess.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

#### General rules:

- If the `interface` contract is applicable in the full hierarchy then `implement` it in the superclass and all subclasses adhere to the `interface` contract automatically.
- You may choose to implement the `interface` in the superclass but make the superclass `abstract` if it does not have enough details to implement the `interface` methods. This way you can enforce the subclasses to adhere to the `interface` contract.
- If the `interface` contract is not at all relevant to the full hierarchy then implement only in the applicable subclasses.

#### Your case:

In your example, the question is whether interface methods `profit()` and `salary()` applicable to any kind of `Store`? If yes (I assume it is), then go ahead and implement in the superclass. However, you may not be able to compute `profit()` and `salary()` in the `Store` class with the data points available. So, you may choose to declare `Store` class as abstract. In case you can implement these methods make `Store` class concrete.

On the other hand, if the interface methods `profit()` and `salary()` may not be applicable to all kind of `Store`s then go ahead and implement the `interface` only in `Retail` class.

Though I think the first option is the good one however, the choice is yours based on the business scenario.